# How to disable button over class of parent element?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<label class="fileinput-button">
    <span>add file...</span>
    <input type="file" name="file" disabled>
</label>
```

I want to disable the `input` element (button) using the `label`'s class name (without the button's ID).

```
$('label.fileinput-button') ... button ... disable.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('label.fileinput-button input').prop('disabled', true);
```

**Note:** `.prop()` is available since version 1.6

Comment: +1 for using `prop()`, although do note that this only works in jQuery 1.6+

Answer (score 1):

Use the `attr` method to assign the `disabled` property to your named input.

```
$('label.fileinput-button input[name=file]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```